# Jenkins Using Variables in multiple build steps

Tags: jenkins, build, command

So I'm curious to know if, when setting up a Jenkins project, it is possible to use a variable defined in build step A in build step B, when using multiple types of build steps?

Example:
[image]

So would the above scenario be possible in Jenkins? If so what would the syntax be?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will not work because your variable is only set for the first shell build step.

You must install the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and use the following configuration:
[image]

Next, the variable should be define for your build steps.